# Flutter: ChangeNotifierProvider doesn't update value in other screens

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a problem with the ChangeNotifierProvider, I've just started with flutter and cannot implement something seemingly simple.

I have the following provider:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:corso_flutter/errors/network_error.dart';
import 'package:corso_flutter/models/ticket_type.dart';
import 'package:corso_flutter/models/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:corso_flutter/costants.dart';
import 'package:corso_flutter/models/virtual_tour.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class ApiService extends ChangeNotifier {

  bool _is_logged = false;

  bool get is_logged => _is_logged;

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>>? getUser(String email, String password) async {

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        "${ApiCostants.base_url}${ApiCostants.user_endpoint}/login?user=$email&password=$password"),
        headers: <String, String>{"authorization": ApiCostants.basic_auth,
        });

    if ( response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299 ) {
      throw NetworkError(response.statusCode, response.reasonPhrase);
    }

    var body = jsonDecode(response.body);

    if ( body["error"] != true ) {
      _is_logged = true;
      print(is_logged);
      notifyListeners();
    }

    return body;

  }

}
```

When I log in and go to change the variable _is_logged, the variable is not correctly updated in the other screens, but is always false and i don't understand why.

This is my main.dart:

```
import 'package:corso_flutter/RouteGenerator.dart';
import 'package:corso_flutter/screens/HomePage.dart';
import 'package:corso_flutter/services/ApiService.dart';
import 'package:corso_flutter/shared.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:skeletons/skeletons.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() {
  Paint.enableDithering = true;
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => ApiService(),
      child: DiscoveryMuseum(),
    )
  );
}

class DiscoveryMuseum extends StatefulWidget {
  const DiscoveryMuseum({super.key});

  @override
  State<DiscoveryMuseum> createState() => _DiscoveryMuseumState();
}

class _DiscoveryMuseumState extends State<DiscoveryMuseum> {

  Map<int, Color> color =
  {
    50:Color.fromRGBO(0,0,0, .1),
    100:Color.fromRGBO(0,0,0, .2),
    200:Color.fromRGBO(0,0,0, .3),
    300:Color.fromRGBO(0,0,0, .4),
    400:Color.fromRGBO(0,0,0, .5),
    500:Color.fromRGBO(0,0,0, .6),
    600:Color.fromRGBO(0,0,0, .7),
    700:Color.fromRGBO(0,0,0, .8),
    800:Color.fromRGBO(0,0,0, .9),
    900:Color.fromRGBO(0,0,0, 1),
  };

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    timeDilation = 2.0;
    return SkeletonTheme(
      shimmerGradient: const LinearGradient(
        colors: [
          Color(0xFFD8E3E7),
          Color(0xFFC8D5DA),
          Color(0xFFD8E3E7),
        ],
        stops: [
          0.1,
          0.3,
          0.9,
        ],
      ),
      darkShimmerGradient: const LinearGradient(
        colors: [
          Color(0xFF222222),
          Color(0xFF242424),
          Color(0xFF2B2B2B),
          Color(0xFF242424),
          Color(0xFF222222),
        ],
        stops: [
          0.0,
          0.2,
          0.5,
          0.8,
          1,
        ],
        begin: Alignment(-2.4, -0.2),
        end: Alignment(2.4, 0.2),
        tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
      ),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Discovery Museum 2.0',
        theme: ThemeData(
          // primarySwatch: MaterialColor(0xFF000000, color),
          // colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.black),
          useMaterial3: true,
          primaryColor: Colors.black,
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          fontFamily: 'Philosopher',
        ),
        // home: MyHomePage(title: 'Discovery Museum 2.0'),
        home: HomePage(),
        onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And even trying to display the variable on a simple page it always comes out false:

```
import 'package:corso_flutter/services/ApiService.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
        child: Center(
            child: Text(context.watch<ApiService>().is_logged.toString())
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I also tried using `Provider.of<ApiService>(context, listen: false).is_logged.toString()` but it always comes out false even after login.